# Using pandas to load data into Django SQLite causes Exception Value: foreign key mismatch

Tags: django, pandas, sqlite

Is there a reason that I can't place data in sqlite(SQL) using pandas in this situation for a Django model?

I would like to use pandas to do some data cleanup and merging of data, then put it into SQL. Before doing the pandas I created my django model.

models.py

```
# myapp
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User 

class Agency(models.Model):
    system_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    county = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    system_type_tuple = [('ED', 'School'),('PG','Power Generation'),('TF','Some other Facility'),('UN','Unknown')]
    system_type = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=system_type_tuple, default= 'UN')
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=5, null=True, blank=True)
    agency_no = models.CharField(max_length=7, primary_key=True, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.agency_no

class SitePart(models.Model):
    system_no = models.ForeignKey('Agency', on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='agency_no', null=True, blank=True,)
    part_name = models.CharField(max_length=125) 
    status_tuple = [('AB','Abandoned'),('AC','Active Compliant'),('DS','Destroyed'),('NP','Need Permit'),('SB','Stand By waiting acitvation')]
    status = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=status_tuple, default= 'SB')

    sys_site_n = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.part_name
```

To create the SQL database for the above model, I type into terminal the commands:

- python manage.py makemigrations myapp
- python manage.py migrate

My pandas_script.py is like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3 as sql
import openpyxl
import numpy as np

conn = sql.connect('C:path_to/Django/my_project/db.sqlite3')
support_dir = "C:/.../support/"
file1 = support_dir + 'file1.xlsx'
file2 = support_dir + 'file2.xlsx'

df1 = pd.read_excel(open(file1, 'rb'), engine='openpyxl', sheet_name="Sheet1",  usecols = 'A,B,D:G')
df2 = pd.read_excel(open(file2, 'rb'), engine='openpyxl', sheet_name="Sheet1",  usecols = 'A,C,F')

# then there is splits, renaming, merging, replace nulls, filtering, change column names...

dfa.sort_values(by=['agency_no'], inplace=True)
print(dfa.head())
print(dfa.shape)
dfa.to_sql('myapp_agency', conn, index=False, if_exists='replace')
```

I then runserver and navigate to my model admin site and try adding in an sitepart entry. When the save is clicked I get an error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users...\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
> return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
> File "C:\Users...\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 413, in execute
> return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
> sqlite3.OperationalError: foreign key mismatch - "myapp_sitepart" referencing "myapp_agency"

Comment: Is this really related to the SQL _language_? I see no SQL above. Do you expect an SQL answer?

Comment: Does the SQLite primary key get messed up when injecting the data through pandas dfa.to_sql(...)? If you think I should take the SQL tag off I can.